# "Eines der wichtigsten Themen", "einer der wichtigsten Themen" or something else

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

As the title says, what is the right way to say "one of the most important (any noun)"?

For example:

> Algorithm, one of the most important topics of informatics.

Is *ein* related to topics or is it related to algorithm?

Comment: It's ***das** Thema*, so it has to be *eine**s***.

Answer (score 3):

For you specific example "eine**s** der wichtigsten" is correct.

However you can't generalize it the way you did in your first question with the added *any noun*, because it always depends on the specific noun. See the following examples:

> **der** Mann (masculine) -> **einer** der wichtigsten Männer
>
> **die** Frau (feminine) -> **eine** der wichtigsten Frauen
>
> **das** Kind (neuter) -> **eines** der wichtigsten Kinder