# Why not "einer der Schlimmstes"?

Tags: word-usage

I did consult a dictionary/duden. Duden does not have an entry for "Schlimmste". This is why I am asking the question here:

In DWDS one always finds,

> einer der schlimmsten.

But what is wrong with

> einer der Schlimmstes?

Comment: See [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:schlimm). We need a genitive plural here and *schlimmstes* is singular, accusative (neuter) in mixed declension, where weak declension is needed.

Comment: For further examples and some discussion of the construction with indefinite pronoun *einer, eines, eine* plus genitive plural, see: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27608/35111 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/53079/35111 https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41091/35111

Comment: To clarify a bit, "*Schlimmste*" is not a normal noun, but a nominalized adjective, in other words an adjective that's been turned into a noun. They are declined like adjectives, so you wouldn't expect "*Schlimmst-*" to have an "*-es*" ending, not following a definite article and not in the genitive case.